# Upload multiple attachments via Jira API using UrlFetchApp.fetch

Tags: google-apps-script, jira-rest-api

I am using google app script server side coding to upload multiple files using Jira Rest API. I have used urlFetchApp.fetch() method for it. The payload i am passing is file blob data with 'Content-Type: false' as i am unable to pass it as formData through server side coding.
With this approach i am able to pass single file at a time to Jira attachments API, I have to call Jira API for each file.
Below is sample code,

```
function updateJiraTicket(fileUploadArr, ticketId){
  const jira_Api = getJiraInstanceKeys();
  const JIRA_URL= jira_Api["URL"] + ticketId + "/attachments";
  const JIRA_LOGIN = jira_Api["LOGINNAME"];
  const JIRA_PASSWORD = jira_Api["PASSWORD"];
  
  const PROJECT = jira_Api["PROJECT"];
 
 //fileUploadArr format getting passed from file upload UI side control
 //fileUploadArr = [{“fileData”:”{base64 file data}”, “fileType”:”image/jpg”,”fileName”:”testimg1”},{“fileData”:”{base64 file data}”, “fileType”:”image/jpg”,”fileName”:”testimg2”}]

  fileUploadArr.forEach(function(arr) {
      let file = getFile(arr.fileData, arr.fileType, arr.fileName);
      let formdata = {'file' : file };
      let params = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
           'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(JIRA_LOGIN+':'+JIRA_PASSWORD),
           'Content-Type': false,
           'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check'
          },
          "payload": formdata,
           muteHttpExceptions: true
      }
      let result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(JIRA_URL, params);
      let response = result.getContentText();
  })
}

function getFile(data, type, name) {
 var file = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(data), type, name);
 return file;
}
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What is your question?